# How to install chrony on redhat 8 minimal

Tags: redhat, chrony

Im using keycloak docker image and need to synchronize time with chrony. however I cannot install chrony, because its not in repository i assume.

I use image from *https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak* 
ist based on *registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8-minimal*

Steps to reproduce:

```
~$ docker run -d --rm -p 8080:8080 --name keycloak jboss/keycloak
~$ docker exec -it -u root keycloak bash
root@707c136d9c8a /]#  microdnf install chrony                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
error: No package matches 'chrony'
```

I'm not able to find working repo which provides chrony for redhat 8 minimal

Answer (score -1):

Apparently i need synchronize time on host system, nothing to do with container itself.. Silly me, i need a break..